# The same query sometimes will return 0 rows, which it should not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an automated query to run at every morning. Usually it would return a table normally. But sometimes it just return 0 rows. After a while, if I rerun the query, it gives the expected table normally. What will be the issue? Below is the query I used.

```
select c.Y_W as [Year Week]
      ,min(cast(CI.[Contract Date] as date)) as [1st Day of Week]
      ,sum(case when datename(dw,CI.[Contract Date])='Sunday' then 1 else 0 end) [Sunday]
      ,sum(case when datename(dw,CI.[Contract Date])='Monday' then 1 else 0 end) [Monday]
      ,sum(case when datename(dw,CI.[Contract Date])='Tuesday' then 1 else 0 end) [Tuesday]
      ,sum(case when datename(dw,CI.[Contract Date])='Wednesday' then 1 else 0 end) [Wednesday]
      ,sum(case when datename(dw,CI.[Contract Date])='Thursday' then 1 else 0 end) [Thursday]
      ,sum(case when datename(dw,CI.[Contract Date])='Friday' then 1 else 0 end) [Friday]
      ,sum(case when datename(dw,CI.[Contract Date])='Saturday' then 1 else 0 end) [Saturday]
from TABLE.Coninfo CI with (NOLOCK)
left join TABLE.Fiscal_cal c with (NOLOCK) on CI.[Contract Date] = c.Dt
where CI.[Status] in ('A','B','C')
      and datediff(wk,CI.[Contract Date],getdate())<=12
group by c.Y_W
order by c.Y_W
```

I tried re run the query after I found it return 0 rows. Usually it's half hour later, everything back to normal again.

In the most of time, I will get a table like this.
[The table supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkA26.png)
But this morning. it becomes like this.
[The table missing all rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic5W8.png)

Comment: Rows can be skipped or duplicated with `NOLOCK` or `READ UNCOMMITTED`.  Don't use those if you need accurate results.

Comment: IS `[Contract Date]` nullable?

Comment: I bet a schema named "TABLE" is fun to work with...

Comment: most likely something wrong with your infrastructure that runs the query, unless you have something weird going on with your tables

Comment: perhaps some data is getting cleared / updated somehow, who knows

Comment: Those date shorthands are sort of ugly to work with. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Something isn't quite making sense here though. Your first column alias is "First day of week" but then in your where predicate you get anything from the last 12 weeks. Then your query has invalid syntax. You omitted the "join" keyword in what I assume is a left join to Fiscal_cal. This all indicates that what you posted is not your actual query. If you don't provide all the information the best anybody can do to help you is guess.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I just rename the table name during the post..It is not its real name =)

Comment: @SeanLange This table is supposed to track past 12x7 days' sales. I have attached a sample image. I was renaming the table name and mis delete the 'join'. beside that and the table name, else is identical.

Comment: @DanGuzman hi thanks for answering. My question then will be even it is reading uncommitted data, will it at least return something instead of nothing?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes, it is nullable.

Comment: Using NOLOCK it can and will randomly return duplicate and even skip rows. This has been well documented. It is far more sinister than just "dirty reads".

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: @Shawwang, rows can be skipped or duplicated if data movement occurs during the scam. So it is possible for no rows to be returned even when rows qualify (committed or not).

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. Really appreciate it!